# Interesting piece of code inside a trait in Laravel Framework 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, overriding, traits

I was wondering what was the purpose of the following piece of code:

[image]

I saw it and kind of dug into the code but I can't FULLY understand it. I assume that it is saying to use those 2 methods (redirectPath and getGuard) from the trait AuthenticatesUsers instead of their respective inside RegistersUsers? Maybe some kind of override?

Thank you for you help and your explanation!

Cheers!

Comment: post code as text, not a image

Comment: Google > keywods: "php insteadof". You insta-get the result.

Answer (score 1):

From the official PHP documentation regarding [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> If two Traits insert a method with the same name, a fatal error is
>   produced, if the conflict is not explicitly resolved.
>
> To resolve naming conflicts between Traits used in the same class, the
>   insteadof operator needs to be used to choose exactly one of the
>   conflicting methods.
>
> Since this only allows one to exclude methods, the as operator can be
>   used to allow the inclusion of one of the conflicting methods under
>   another name.